# cosmos db multiple access conditions

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible in some way to have multiple access conditions that prevent the document to be saved to cosmos if they isn't met.

Today I have an accesscondition on the ETag, to prevent an old version of the document to be saved. But I want to have another condition based on the status of the document. So if the document in my store is in a 'closed' status, it will prevent any from modifying it.

I can always do a `load -> check -> save` routine, but the accesscondition works like a charm for the ETag so I wonder if there is a way to have multiple access condition specified when saving the document.

Best Regards
Magnus

Answer (score 0):

Based on the detailed statements in below blogs,

1.https://codeopinion.com/documentdb-optimistic-concurrency/

2.https://chapsas.com/understanding-optimistic-concurrency-in-cosmos-db/

`ETAG` in cosmos db only provides optimistic concurrency and can be used with an `AccessCondition` in order to ensure that if the document changed between the retrieval and the manipulation attempt of the document.

[AccessConditionType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.accesscondition.type?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_AccessCondition_Type) only has `IfMatch` or `IfNoneMatch`,no more other status.

[image]

So,back to your requirements,it seems that you have to add `ifClosed` item in your document and check it when you do modification to implement your needs.